# Get the week of the month in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am developing a Java application using MySQL. I need to know which is the week of each month, of the stored dates. Is there any MySQL function for that ? Basically , if i was to use this for the current date (13.09) it would show me its in week number 2 and tomorrow it will be week number 3.

Comment: how do you want to count weeks? For example, the 01-March-2015 is on a Sunday, is it week 1? And what about 02-March-2015? is it week 2?

Comment: there is a week of year available, with about 8 options for what is considered the first week. A nice way to blow an hour figuring that one out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can play with the [WEEK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function, and see if it suits your needs. Here I'm using `WEEK(date, 3)` that will return the week of the year from 1 to 53, starting from Mondays:

```
set @my_date = '2015-09-13';

SELECT
  WEEK(@my_date, 3) -
  WEEK(@my_date - INTERVAL DAY(@my_date)-1 DAY, 3) + 1
  AS week_number;
```

- `WEEK(date, 3)` will return the week of the year of the selected date
- `WEEK(date - INTERVAL DAY(@my_date)-1 DAY, 3)` will return the week of the year of the first day of the month of the selected date

It will return 1 for 01-March-2015 (because it's the first day of the month so it's week 1) and 2 for 02-March-2015 (because weeks starts from Mondays, so it's a new week). If this is not the desidered behaviour you should specify your requirements more precisely.

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/20346).

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, there isn't a "weekofmonth" function, but you could use [`dayofmonth`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth), and manipulate the result a bit:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE(), 
       FLOOR((DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) - 1) / 7) + 1 AS week_of_month
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

Create a mysql function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `WEEK_OF_MONTH`(
    datee   DATE
    ) RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE DayNamee VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE StartDatee DATE;
    DECLARE DayNumber INT DEFAULT 0;

    SET DayNamee = (SELECT DAYNAME(datee));
    SET StartDatee = (SELECT FIRST_DAY(datee));

    WHILE StartDatee <= datee DO
        IF DayNamee = DAYNAME(StartDatee) THEN
            SET DayNumber = DayNumber + 1;
        END IF;
        SET StartDatee = DATE_ADD( StartDatee, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END WHILE;

    RETURN DayNumber;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Call as --

```
SELECT `WEEK_OF_MONTH`('2018-12-31');
```

Result : 5